# Get data form multi table in Codeigniter using SQL Join

Tags: sql, database, codeigniter, join

Receiving error like Not unique table/alias: 'provinces' , below function is of model function , I create this function in model but getting error table/alias

```
function get_data_three_tbl(){

                $this->db->select('blood_donors.id, blood_donors.full_name, blood_donors.area, blood_donors.email, blood_donors.phone, provinces.province_name,districts.district_name, tehsils.tehsil_name, blood_groups.group_name');
                $this->db->from ( 'blood_donors, provinces, districts, tehsils, blood_groups ' );
                $this->db->where('blood_donors.is_deleted',1);
                $this->db->join('provinces','provinces.province_id = blood_donors.province');
                $this->db->join('districts','districts.district_id = blood_donors.district');
                $this->db->join('tehsils','tehsils.tehsil_id = blood_donors.tehsil');
                $this->db->join('blood_groups','blood_groups.id = blood_donors.blood_goup');
                $query = $this->db->get();
                if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
                return $query->result_array();
                else
                return FALSE;
    }
```

Comment: If you are using JOIN function why you use same tables in FROM?

Comment: if i delete the "FROM" then also  getting errors

Comment: if I remove "FROM" then getting error below.
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'JOIN `provinces` ON `provinces`.`province_id` = `blood_donors`.`province` JOIN `' at line 2

Comment: First, try to create query on MySQL. Then move to codeigniter query helper might be there is some miss match ids issue.

Answer (score 0):

Change the `from()` call to

```
$this->db->from('blood_donors');
```

The `join` statements take care of the other tables. Having the table names in both the `from` and `join` statements is the reason for the not unique error.